# Snorkeling in southern Japan?

Tags: japan, diving, kyushu

Are there any good snorkeling sites around Kyushu in southern Japan? Is it warm enough to do this in April? (Context: newbie snorkelers... one or two days. Preferably not an island outside of Kyushu.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about The Kyushu region (including okinawa and the islands)

I recently returned from ishigaki (an island in the Kyushu region). We did snorkelling and scuba out there.

Most dive schools will not take Non Japanese newbies. As we don't speak japanese we found an excellent english speaking dive school.
If you're looking to go Snorkelling through a dive school i'd reccomend Dive school Umicoza.
A Day's **Snorkelling** will cost 8,400 yen.
This includes:

- hotel pickup
- equipement rental
- boat cover
- Experienced Guides
- lunch
- photos of your dive
- Drop off at your Hotel

I went in september and they had 2 english speaking guides (one also spoke chinese, and french). We did Scuba and snorkelling with them and the marine life was spectacular on both. The guides were awesome and it was just an amazing day.
Their website is here

[Dive School Umicoza](http://www.umicoza.com/english/)

If you'd just like to go to the dive site without going through a dive school (i really don't recommend this) then here's a link to it on google maps.

[Snorkelling site](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=24.420317,124.078365&num=1&t=h&vpsrc=6&hl=en&ie=UTF8&ll=24.421362,124.100275&spn=0.042124,0.092697&z=14)

The sea temperature will be fine in april as ishigaki's sea temperature ranges from 21°C in winter to 29°C in summer

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: This is a really good answer @zeocrash but I think you should emphasize the snorkelling part of the answer over the diving part since the question is specifically about snorkelling and they're even newbies at that. It is tagged as diving too so sorry if that threw you off the scent a bit, we're thinking of having the diving tag also cover snorkelling.

Comment: I thought i did emphasize the snorkelling part of the answer. All the details of the Dive school package is for their snorkelling introductory package. I mentioned that i did scuba also. Terms such as "dive site" are common between snorkelling and scuba. I only mention scuba as it is worth doing too if you get the chance out there.

Comment: sorry i realise that came off as rather agressive, i didn't mean to sound like that

Comment: Oh sorry if I read it wrong, especially the part about the schools not taking non japanese newbies made me think it was something PADI-like.

Comment: Nah it's just that most schools don't have any english speaking guides as english isn't commonly spoken on the island. I can't recommend ishigaki enough. After my time there this year i want to move out there and become a scuba/snorkel guide